# How can I get the current Leaflet map zoom level?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to get the zoom level of a map in real time to make a button that locks the zoom with the current value. I have tried using getMapZoom and getZoom but both give me an undefined value. I think I'm not using the correct ref but I haven't been able to find much documentation about it. Here's the code:

```
<Map className="map-layer" 
          center={center} 
          onoverlayadd={this.overlayadd} 
          onoverlayremove={this.overlayremove}
          ondragend={this.zoomChange}
          onzoomend={console.log('Zoom: ' + this.mapRef.leafletElement.getMapZoom())}
          zoom={this.state.zoom}
          ref={this.mapRef}
          preferCanvas={false}
          animate={true}
          scrollWheelZoom={this.state.zoomLock ? false : true}
          doubleClickZoom={this.state.zoomLock ? false : true}
          touchZoom={this.state.zoomLock ? false : true}
          maxZoom={7}
          minZoom={7}

                    >
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In pure leaflet if you defined map as `const map = L.map("map", options)` than you just call `map.getZoom()`.

In constructor `this.mapRef = React.createRef()`
In Map element:

```
    ref={this.mapRef}
    onzoomend={() => console.log(this.mapRef.current.leafletElement.getZoom()}
```

Comment: I have tried that yet, throws an error. `Cannot read property 'getZoom' of undefined`

Comment: Try `ref={(ref) => { this.mapRef = ref }}` instead of `ref={this.mapRef}`.

Comment: I haven't noticed you weren't passing the function to the `onzoomend`. I updated the answer. You should pass functions to other onevent handlers too.

Answer (score 3):

The following code works in JavaScript:

```
map.on('zoomend', function (e) {
    console.log(e.target._zoom);
});
```

Comment: In Javascript, developers usually prepend their variable names with an underscore to denote that this is a private variable and it should not be used outside the class scope. So this practice might also be valid here and the _zoom variable isn't meant to be read directly.

Comment: FYI the method you're using here is a jQuery method, not core JS.
https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler

Answer (score -1):

In react You can get zoomLevel by using getZoom method() and using useRef.

```
1) const mapRef = useRef(null) 

2) const getMapZoom = () => {
 return mapRef && console.log("object", mapRef.current.getZoom());
 };

 3) <MapContainer
    className="markercluster-map"
    center={center}
    zoom={ZOOM_LEVEL}
    maxZoom={MAX_ZOOM}
    ref={mapRef}
    whenCreated={(mapInstance) => (mapRef.current = mapInstance)}
    whenReady={() => {}}
    >
```